# ASP.NET 2 Webforms hosting on microsoft azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, crystal-reports-2008, cloud-hosting

We would like to host our web application with microsoft azure but some few clarifications are need before we can go ahead.
Do we need to use PaaS or LaaS for these:

- Application is on .Net 2.0
- Full Trust mode
- Crystal Reports used, not the viewer but through a dataset and sent directly to pdf or excel, therefore the crystal libraries are need
  version: 10.5.3700.0

I need your help to be able to decide.
Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I believe all your requirements will work as either PaaS or IaaS.

Azure based APIs are not in .net 2.0, but you should be able to run 2.0 code on Azure's 3.5

Answer (score 0):

- **Application is on .Net 2.0** : No problem with that, you can run .Net 2.0 in any higher version, nevertheless Is best if you test your solution compiling on .net 3.5 because 2.0 is out of support.
- **Full Trust mode** : Azure websites runs on Full trust mode by default
- **Crystal Reports used**: You can add the assemblies required by your application in azure websites. Just mark the **Copy Local** assembly reference property reference in Visual Studio